# Critical group and morse Lemma

Tags: analysis, algebraic-topology, morse-theory

I have this theorem with a part of it's prove 
[image]

I have two questions:

1) what is the spectral decomposition of A ?

2)How to see that $B_{\varepsilon}\cap f_0 = \lbrace x\in H,||x||\leq \varepsilon , ||y_+||\leq ||y_-||,y_{±}=(±AP_{±})^{\frac12}x\rbrace$

Please,

Thank you .

Comment: When they talk about the spectral decomposition of $A$ I guess that they mean that $H_+$ (resp. $H_-$) is the space of eigenvectors of $A$ with positive (resp. negative) eigenvalue.

Comment: By the way, what is $f_0$? And $\theta$?

Comment: $\theta$ is the origine of $B_{\varepsilon}$, and $f_0$ is level set of f, not above the level 0